# How to use OSGi services in Tapestry

Tags: web-applications, osgi, tapestry, osgi-bundle, wab

I have my Tapestry web application that offers full CRUD functionality for some data set.
So far, I've been using mocks to develop and test it.

However, I need to now replace that mock by an OSGi service (ran with Felix).

My main questions/issues are:

1. Do I need to inject the OSGi service into my tapestry app and if so, how to do it?
2. Assuming it's injected, are there any practices on how to use it? Any special ways I should call the methods or anything like that?
3. Do I need to do something with it after I've called the methods I need, or is that done automatically?
4. Do I need to worry about `HttpService` (I glanced some complaints about it, but didn't quite understand it)

To provide you with some context, this is how I'm doing it now

```
public class MyPage {
    ...
    @Inject
    private MyDao dao;
    ...
    @Property
    private List<Entry> entries;
    ...
    void onPrepareForRender() {
        ...
        this.entries = this.dao.getAll()
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

What I would like is to replace `MyDao dao` with an OSGi service that provides the same functionality so I can use it in `onPrepareForRender` method, for example.

I can safely assume that the OSGi bundle associated with the service will already be runnning.

The rest of the application is made as an OSGi application.
I've added/changed stuff in my pom.xml (maven-bundle-plugin, added some manifest entries as instructed in http://www.javabeat.net/2011/11/writing-an-osgi-web-application/).

However, it still doesn't work.

I'm trying to convert my WAR to WAB, btw.

Thank you in advance :)

## EDIT: Problem while converting and deploying from WAR to WAB

When I package my web-app as `war` stuff works fine. However, when I package it as `bundle`, and try to deploy it in GlassFish, I get the following error message:

> Error occurred during deployment: There is no installed container
>   capable of handling this application admin-war. Please see server.log
>   for more details.

When I go to server.log, here's what it says:

```
[#|2013-08-27T17:11:57.600+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|uploadFileName=admin-war-2.01-SNAPSHOT.jar|#]

[#|2013-08-27T17:11:57.920+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8031: Ignoring WEB-INF/ because the containing archive C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\admin-war recorded it as a pre-existing stale file|#]

[#|2013-08-27T17:11:57.939+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared|_ThreadID=33;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8031: Ignoring WEB-INF/ because the containing archive C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\admin-war recorded it as a pre-existing stale file|#]

[#|2013-08-27T17:11:57.972+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8031: Ignoring WEB-INF/ because the containing archive C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\admin-war recorded it as a pre-existing stale file|#]

[#|2013-08-27T17:11:57.973+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8031: Ignoring WEB-INF/ because the containing archive C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\admin-war recorded it as a pre-existing stale file|#]

[#|2013-08-27T17:11:57.974+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8031: Ignoring WEB-INF/ because the containing archive C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\admin-war recorded it as a pre-existing stale file|#]

[#|2013-08-27T17:11:57.990+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8031: Ignoring WEB-INF/ because the containing archive C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\admin-war recorded it as a pre-existing stale file|#]

[#|2013-08-27T17:11:57.991+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8031: Ignoring WEB-INF/ because the containing archive C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\admin-war recorded it as a pre-existing stale file|#]

[#|2013-08-27T17:11:58.006+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8031: Ignoring WEB-INF/ because the containing archive C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\admin-war recorded it as a pre-existing stale file|#]

[#|2013-08-27T17:11:58.008+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8031: Ignoring WEB-INF/ because the containing archive C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\admin-war recorded it as a pre-existing stale file|#]

[#|2013-08-27T17:11:58.008+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8031: Ignoring WEB-INF/ because the containing archive C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\admin-war recorded it as a pre-existing stale file|#]

[#|2013-08-27T17:11:58.024+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8031: Ignoring WEB-INF/ because the containing archive C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\admin-war recorded it as a pre-existing stale file|#]

[#|2013-08-27T17:11:58.025+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8031: Ignoring WEB-INF/ because the containing archive C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\admin-war recorded it as a pre-existing stale file|#]

[#|2013-08-27T17:11:58.026+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Module type not recognized for module C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\admin-war|#]

[#|2013-08-27T17:11:58.026+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|There is no installed container capable of handling this application admin-war|#]

[#|2013-08-27T17:11:58.087+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: There is no installed container capable of handling this application admin-war. Please see server.log for more details.|#]
```

Comment: __I can safely assume that the OSGi bundle associated with the service will already be runnning.__ Wow! Magic! Done the impossible! :-)

Comment: Well, that's what they assured me of :P

Comment: Ahh, then I have a nice bridge for sale, nice property, located in New York. Really cheap. :-)

Comment: You could: Write a hello world tapestry app that works as OSGi based webapp, check how Spring tapestry filter works (2-3 classes only), write a filter that uses OSGi service instead of Spring application context beans. And finally share the code of your filter on GitHub :).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that familiar with OSGI but you will need to use build* methods in your AppModule to provide the DAO's. In my example below, I have assumed that OsgiBundle is a way of accessing OSGI services, I have no idea what the actual OSGI class is called.

eg:

```
public class MyAppModule {
    public void contributeApplicationDefaults(MappedConfiguration<String, String> config) {
        config.add("osgi.path", "path/to/osgi.xml");
    }

    public OsgiBundle buildOsgiBundle(@Symbol("osgi.path") String osgiPath) {
        // lookup the OSGI bundle somehow
    }

    public MyDao buildMyDao(OsgiBundle osgiBundle) {
        return osgiBundle.getService(MyDao.class);
    }   

    public SomeOtherDao buildSomeOtherDao(OsgiBundle osgiBundle) {
        return osgiBundle.getService(SomeOtherDao.class);
    }   
}
```

If you want deeper integration (ie automatically publish all OSGI services as Tapestry IOC services) then take a look at the TapestrySpringFilter which publishes all spring beans as Tapestry IOC services.

Comment: I'll give it a try then :)
BTW, this is the 3rd time I see you answering my questions about Tapestry :) Thx for the effort :)